# Anybody using AmaterasUML in Eclipse?

Tags: uml

Does it automatically creates the sequence diagram? Or we have to drag and drop the related Java files and then manually create the sequence diagram?

This was the only link I could find on Google:
http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are using AmatersUML (but other tool/libraries  from the same Takezoe author too: [Mirage](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/site/mirage/welcome.html), [AmatersERD](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasERD), and ClickIDE Eclipse plug-in for [Apache Click](http://click.apache.org/))

It can automatically create a sequence diagram by providing it a Stack Trace - you just need to copy and paste one.
It also has a API that allows you to generate Sequence Diagrams (e.g. you can combine this API with a logging framework, or if you need sequence diagrams for unknown code, than you need to use the Java profiling API with it to instrumentate and output those names that are executed).